# Stuck in a virtual console after init, not sure how to proceed

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, linux-mint

When I turned on my laptop today this message (for a first time greeted me)

> login as: root root@10.10.10.158's password: Last login: Sun Sep  7
>   10:25:51 2008 from 10.10.10.41 Linux debian 2.6.18-6-686 #1 SMP Tue
>   Jun 17 21:31:27 UTC 2008 i686
>
> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free
>   software; the exact distribution terms for each program are described
>   in the individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
>   permitted by applicable law. debian:~#

After that it asks me for a password and login, which I enter and then I got stuck in ssh. How can I exit command line and get to my usual GUI system (Linux Mint)? 
Thank you

Comment: try the command: start x

Comment: it says that ,start x is currently not installed

Comment: sorry, you are using mint run "sudo service lightdm start"

Comment: sudo service lightdm start    unrecognized service

Comment: are you using linux mint 13?  "sudo service mdm start"

Comment: unrecognized service

Comment: OK, Time to post your system, mint version, and specs and let us know what the last thing was you did before you shut off your machine.

Comment: uname -a:   Debian 3.2.0-2-486

Comment: I've installed and unistalled dropbox from software centre and the I've rebooted a system and get stuck in command line since then

Answer (score 0):

The default runlevel on distros such as Mint and Ubuntu will start a GUI login manager. Examples of such are GDM, XDM, KDM. A couple of things could prevent it from running, listing here from the most likely to the most unlikely:

- The driver for your video card is not installed (or was not upgraded automatically)
- The login manager cant start because some dependencies are "too new" due to an upgrade
- The default runlevel has been changed to "multiuser" from "graphical inteface" in /etc/inittab

Package dependencies sometimes get messed up the fist time you use APT (software center) to upgrade or install software. It's usually resolved by configuring APT properly, fetching an update and then re-installing the problematic packages.

What I'm saying can be summarized with: consult the Mint user manual or wiki on the subject of "How do I install drivers for my graphics card". You will probably have to focus on the command line solutions.